# WebGL bitcoin miner not checking nonce

Tags: javascript, webgl, bitcoin

I've been playing around with the bitcoin miner found at: https://github.com/derjanb/hamiyoca. After trial and error of changing things around everywhere, I finally was able to get the basic javascript and web worker implementations running.

I decided to test the WebGL miner when I noticed the function **is_golden_hash** is not called at all during the script, but is still defined. I don't really understand the code much because I have no experience with WebGL, but was curious as to where it would go. I assume it would go somewhere on line **201** or **213**. Can anyone help me with this?

(glminer.js):

```
var vShaderQuellcode;
var fShaderQuellcode;

var dataLoc;
var hash1Loc;
var midstateLoc;
var targetLoc;
var nonceLoc;

var maxNonce = 0xFFFFFFFF;
var maxCnt = 0;
var reportPeriod = 1000;
var useTimeout = true;
var TotalHashes = 0;
var gl;
var canvas;
var debug = false;
var buf;

var width;
var height;

function throwOnGLError(err, funcName, args) {
    throw WebGLDebugUtils.glEnumToString(err) + " was caused by call to" + funcName;
};

function meinWebGLStart(threads) {
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        if (debug || true) document.body.appendChild(canvas)
        canvas.height = 1;
        canvas.width = threads;

        var names = [ "webgl", "experimental-webgl", "moz-webgl", "webkit-3d" ];
        for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
            try { 
                gl = canvas.getContext(names[i]);
                if (gl) { break; }
            } catch (e) { }
        }

        if(!gl) {
            alert("Fehler: WebGL-Context konnte nicht initialisiert werden");
        }

        var program = gl.createProgram();


        vShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        gl.shaderSource(vShader,vShaderQuellcode);
        gl.compileShader(vShader);
        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vShader));
        }
        gl.attachShader(program,vShader);

        fShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        gl.shaderSource(fShader,fShaderQuellcode);
        gl.compileShader(fShader);
        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fShader));
        }
        gl.attachShader(program,fShader);

        gl.linkProgram(program);
        gl.useProgram(program);

        gl.clearColor ( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
        gl.clear ( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        var posAtrLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPos");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray( posAtrLoc );

        var h =  [0x6a09, 0xe667, 0xbb67, 0xae85,
                  0x3c6e, 0xf372, 0xa54f, 0xf53a,
                  0x510e, 0x527f, 0x9b05, 0x688c,
                  0x1f83, 0xd9ab, 0x5be0, 0xcd19];

        var k =  [0x428a, 0x2f98, 0x7137, 0x4491,
                  0xb5c0, 0xfbcf, 0xe9b5, 0xdba5,
                  0x3956, 0xc25b, 0x59f1, 0x11f1,
                  0x923f, 0x82a4, 0xab1c, 0x5ed5,
                  0xd807, 0xaa98, 0x1283, 0x5b01,
                  0x2431, 0x85be, 0x550c, 0x7dc3,
                  0x72be, 0x5d74, 0x80de, 0xb1fe,
                  0x9bdc, 0x06a7, 0xc19b, 0xf174,
                  0xe49b, 0x69c1, 0xefbe, 0x4786,
                  0x0fc1, 0x9dc6, 0x240c, 0xa1cc,
                  0x2de9, 0x2c6f, 0x4a74, 0x84aa,
                  0x5cb0, 0xa9dc, 0x76f9, 0x88da,
                  0x983e, 0x5152, 0xa831, 0xc66d,
                  0xb003, 0x27c8, 0xbf59, 0x7fc7,
                  0xc6e0, 0x0bf3, 0xd5a7, 0x9147,
                  0x06ca, 0x6351, 0x1429, 0x2967,
                  0x27b7, 0x0a85, 0x2e1b, 0x2138,
                  0x4d2c, 0x6dfc, 0x5338, 0x0d13,
                  0x650a, 0x7354, 0x766a, 0x0abb,
                  0x81c2, 0xc92e, 0x9272, 0x2c85,
                  0xa2bf, 0xe8a1, 0xa81a, 0x664b,
                  0xc24b, 0x8b70, 0xc76c, 0x51a3,
                  0xd192, 0xe819, 0xd699, 0x0624,
                  0xf40e, 0x3585, 0x106a, 0xa070,
                  0x19a4, 0xc116, 0x1e37, 0x6c08,
                  0x2748, 0x774c, 0x34b0, 0xbcb5,
                  0x391c, 0x0cb3, 0x4ed8, 0xaa4a,
                  0x5b9c, 0xca4f, 0x682e, 0x6ff3,
                  0x748f, 0x82ee, 0x78a5, 0x636f,
                  0x84c8, 0x7814, 0x8cc7, 0x0208,
                  0x90be, 0xfffa, 0xa450, 0x6ceb,
                  0xbef9, 0xa3f7, 0xc671, 0x78f2];

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
        var vertices = new Float32Array([1, 1,-1, 1,
                                         1,-1,-1,-1]);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.vertexAttribPointer(posAtrLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        dataLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "data");
        hash1Loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "hash1");
        midstateLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "midstate");
        targetLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "target");
        nonceLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "nonce_base");

        var hLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "H");
        var kLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "K");

        gl.uniform2fv(hLoc, h);
        gl.uniform2fv(kLoc, k);
}

function readScript(n) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", n, false);
    xhr.send(null);
    var x = xhr.responseText;
    return x;
};

function onl() {
    vShaderQuellcode = readScript('shader-vs.js');
    fShaderQuellcode = readScript('shader-fs.js');
};

function glminer(job, callback) {
    var run = true;

    var next_run = function(job, callback) {
        var nonces_per_pixel = 1;
        var t = job.t === undefined ? 0 : job.t;
        var nonce = job.nonce === undefined ? 0 : job.nonce;
        var threads = width * nonces_per_pixel;
        var curCnt = 0;
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;
        var n;

        var submit_nonce = function() {
            n = derMiner.Util.to_uint16_array(job.nonce);

            job.data[6] = n[0];
            job.data[7] = n[1];

            var r = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < job.half.length; j++)
                r.push(job.half[j]);
            for (var j = 0; j < job.data.length; j++)
                r.push(job.data[j]);

            var ret = derMiner.Util.toPoolString(r, true);

            job.golden_ticket = ret;
            callback(job);
        }

        while(run) {
            n = derMiner.Util.to_uint16_array(nonce);
            gl.uniform2fv(nonceLoc,  n);
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

            if (debug) console.log("w:" + width + " h:" + height);

            gl.readPixels(x, y, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);

            for (var i=0; i<buf.length; i+=4) {
                if (debug) {
                    var out = [];
                    out.push(derMiner.Util.byte_to_hex(buf[i]));
                    out.push(derMiner.Util.byte_to_hex(buf[i+1]));
                    out.push(derMiner.Util.byte_to_hex(buf[i+2]));
                    out.push(derMiner.Util.byte_to_hex(buf[i+3]));
                    console.log("rgba("+(i/4)+"): " + JSON.stringify(out));
                }

                if (nonces_per_pixel == 1) {
                    if (buf[i] == 0 &&
                        buf[i+1] == 0 &&
                        buf[i+2] == 0 &&
                        buf[i+3] == 0) {

                        job.nonce = nonce + i * (nonces_per_pixel / 4);
                        submit_nonce();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (buf[i] != 0 ||
                        buf[i+1] != 0 ||
                        buf[i+2] != 0 ||
                        buf[i+3] != 0) {
                        for (var e = 0; e < 4; e++) {
                            for (var r = 7; r >= 0; r--) {
                                if (buf[i + e] & 1 << r) {
                                    var b = (3 - e) * (nonces_per_pixel / 4) + r;
                                    job.nonce = nonce + i * (nonces_per_pixel / 4) + b;
                                    submit_nonce();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        job.golden_ticket = null;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (nonce >= maxNonce) {
                cb(null);
                break;
            }

            nonce+= threads;
            TotalHashes += threads;

            if (t < (new Date()).getTime()) {
                t = (new Date()).getTime() + reportPeriod;
                job.total_hashes = TotalHashes;
                callback(job);
                TotalHashes = 0;
            }

            if (useTimeout && ++curCnt > maxCnt) {
                curCnt = 0;
                job.nonce = nonce;
                job.t = t;
                var c = function() {
                    next_run(job, callback);
                }
                window.setTimeout(c, 1);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    var intMessage = function(event) {
        if (!event.data || !event.data.run) {
            run = false;
            console.log("worker: forced quit!");
            return;
        }
    };

    var mine = function(job, callback) {

        gl.uniform2fv(dataLoc, job.data);
        gl.uniform2fv(hash1Loc, job.hash1);
        gl.uniform2fv(midstateLoc, job.midstate);
        gl.uniform2fv(targetLoc, job.target);

        width = canvas.width;
        height = canvas.height;

        buf = new Uint8Array(width * height * 4);

        next_run(job, callback);
        return intMessage;
    }

    var is_golden_hash = function(hash, target) {
        var u1 = derMiner.Util.ToUInt32(hash);
        var u2 = derMiner.Util.ToUInt32(target[6]);

        console.log("worker: checking " + u1 + " <= " + u2);
        return (u1 <= u2);
    }

    return mine(job, callback);
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I see reading through the code on his github, this function is not used or needed. It could have been an old function that was used and never removed from the code, or is there for testing / debugging to troubleshoot things if it's not working as intended.

Comment: At what point is the code checking if the current nonce is the solution to the block then?

Comment: When ran, this code says it has found a nonce on the very first try.

Comment: @TimPogue Around line 169 - 172 in glminer.js and work-manager.js line 153 - 155 logs the nonce to the console.